# Menu display issues after upgrading to Sierra

Tags: macos, font

[image: contextual menus without text]I just recently upgraded my Mac and it's having some issues.  It freezes for a few seconds, and when it resumes operation, things just go crazy.  Among other problems, some text is missing, some text is not showing up in the contextual menu.

I thought it might be a font problem or something, so I went to Font Book, tried to validate all the fonts there, and all seems fine.

I hope the screenshots I attached might help.  Thank you.[image: application menu without text]

Comment: Is it just in WhatsApp (your screenshot) or does it happen with other applications, too?  Please update your question to include the type of Mac you have.

Comment: Every other app. It randomly happens. It starts with the MAC being frozen and then all that let loose. It mostly occurs when am on chrome

Comment: @fsb thats another one when am on chrome.

Comment: @philipoghenerobobalogun did you find a fix?

Comment: nope. Am considering doing a clean install as suggested in the answer below, but i'll rather avoid that. Have any solution to offer?

Comment: Nope, I am facing the same issue. Service center to the rescue!

Comment: I have the same issue. I'd rather find a solution to this than doing a clean install, but reinstalling would be my last resort.

Comment: @Ranveer what did they do differently?

Comment: @philipoghenerobobalogun I haven't been there yet, will let you know. Although, from what I feel, Night shift might be a culprit. Do you use Night shift?

Comment: @Ranveer: I don't use night shift and still have the same problem. Actually, my settings are pretty standard. I use the default settings most of the time, even the default background.

Comment: Hey! Did you figure out how to at least get rid of this without restarting the whole system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest a clean install... But when you choose to do it, don't forget the backups first!

You could potentially troubleshoot it and find some corrupt file, but I'd cut the hassling and try a clean one (as it is easy to do and very likely to work).

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do i go about a clean install?