# Menu items disappear, dialog boxes go black on MacOS

Tags: macos, performance

This problem started nearly 4 days ago.
Randomly, while browsing, or more specifically, entering a url in the address bar, my Mac freezes. After a while, it unfreezes but all the menu items disappear and all dialog boxes become black (but stay responsive). Even the windows have weird black areas.
It's not reproducible.
Initially, I thought it was a problem with Google Chrome, but the same happened while I was browsing on Firefox.

I have resetted the NVRAM and SMC, but it doesn't fix my issue.

Has anyone faced a similar problem before? If yes, what was the fix?

The model is a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) and the OS version is Sierra 10.12.4 (16E195).

Comment: What happens in Safari?

Comment: I don't use Safari much, but I guess it's worth trying it out for a few days and see what happens.

Comment: @IconDaemon Plus, this happens randomly, there's no way to reproduce it

Comment: Does it look like the screenshots in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/281284/88313)?  I'm trying to see if they're similar or caused by the same issue in Sierra.

Comment: Yes. Exactly this. Oh no.