# App specific display issues

Tags: finder, display, mojave, hardware

First of all, this is my first question here. So forgive me if I cross any lines.

I am using a Macbook Pro mid-2012 non-retina running Mojave and having this strange problem since months. Some apps, like Apple Photos, PDF Expert, and even finder show invisible graphics & texts here and there.

[image: This is Photos app and the photo exists and can be shared, downloaded etc. but isn't visible]

Next, Finder's tab bar goes black in Light mode and **not so black** in dark mode. In PDF expert the entire PDF text/image disappear randomly.
[image: PDF Expert]

Same used to happen in Google Chrome as well but once I disabled Hardware acceleration in Google Chrome it started working fine.

So, as per my little knowledge Hardware Acceleration is causing the issue. I ended here first and clean installed MacOS but that didn't work. [Menu display issues after upgrading to Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/281284/menu-display-issues-after-upgrading-to-sierra)

Have you ever faced such an issue? How can I solve it?
Thank you!